# ERROR: Unknown procedure: dups2/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Tags: prolog

Im trying to duplicate elements on a list with this code:

```
dups2([],[]).
dups2([H|T],[H,H|Y]) :-
    dups2(T,Y).
```

I'm using the query

```
dups2([1,2,3], X).
```

expecting:

```
X=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR: Unknown procedure: dups2/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It should work. Have you loaded the code into the interpreter? `['/file/path'].` should load the code. If you are using any IDE that supports prolog you can load it in other ways.

Comment: Im using visual studio, so I opened visual in the file directory and called the file with "swipl"

Comment: I am not familiar with visual studio, but try `listing(dups2).` in the repl. It should print out the dups2 code if file is loaded. If the file is not loaded it should complain that dups2 does not exist. You can also try manually loading the file by doing `['path/to/file'].` in the repl.

Comment: Why use Visual Studio for this?  Notepad++ and a terminal window should do at this point, all the rest is distraction. Or use Prolog online via [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/).

Comment: yeah SWISH did the trick, thanks!